# Описание веб-сервиса в формате wsdl

Tags: soap

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется описание SOAP веб-сервиса в формате WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://service.gds.artmark.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="SoapJsonServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://service.gds.artmark.com/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://service.gds.artmark.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.gds.artmark.com/" version="1.0">
...
<xs:element name="getCountries" type="tns:getCountries"/>
<xs:element name="getCountriesResponse" type="tns:getCountriesResponse"/>
...
<xs:complexType name="getVersion">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getVersionResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getArrivalPoints">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dispatchPointId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pattern" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getArrivalPointsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDepotInfo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="depotId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDepotInfoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDispatchPoints">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="regionId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDispatchPointsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="bookOrder">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sales" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="bookOrderResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getCountries">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getCountriesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrder">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paymentMethod" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrderResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getOrder">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getOrderResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="returnTicket">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticketId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="returnTicketResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDocTypes">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDocTypesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getTicket">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticketId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getTicketResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="updateTicket">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticketId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sale" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="updateTicketResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrderWithFare">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paymentMethod" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fares" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comment" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrderWithFareResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cancelTicket">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ticketId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cancelTicketResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRace">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRegions">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="countryId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRegionsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrderEx">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paymentMethod" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="options" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="confirmOrderExResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cancelOrder">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cancelOrderResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="echo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="echoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDepots">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getDepotsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceStops">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceStopsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceSummary">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="uid" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceSummaryResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getPointDepots">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="pointId" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getPointDepotsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceSeats">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaceSeatsResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getTicketTypes">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="raceCode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getTicketTypesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getReference">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getReferenceResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRaces">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dispatchPlaceId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="arrivalPlaceId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="date" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getRacesResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
...
<wsdl:message name="getCountries">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getCountries" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="confirmOrder">
<wsdl:part element="tns:confirmOrder" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getOrder">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getOrder" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="cancelTicketResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:cancelTicketResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="confirmOrderResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:confirmOrderResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDocTypesResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getDocTypesResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDispatchPointsResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getDispatchPointsResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDocTypes">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getDocTypes" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getTicket">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getTicket" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="cancelOrderResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:cancelOrderResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="confirmOrderWithFare">
<wsdl:part element="tns:confirmOrderWithFare" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRace">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getRace" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRegions">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getRegions" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="bookOrderResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:bookOrderResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getTicketTypesResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getTicketTypesResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDepots">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getDepots" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getTicketResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getTicketResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getVersionResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getVersionResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="updateTicketResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:updateTicketResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRaceStops">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getRaceStops" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPointDepotsResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getPointDepotsResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRaceSeats">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getRaceSeats" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getOrderResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getOrderResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getTicketTypes">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getTicketTypes" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getReference">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getReference" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SoapJsonService">
<wsdl:operation name="getVersion">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getVersion" name="getVersion"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getVersionResponse" name="getVersionResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getArrivalPoints">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getArrivalPoints" name="getArrivalPoints"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getArrivalPointsResponse" name="getArrivalPointsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDepotInfo">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getDepotInfo" name="getDepotInfo"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getDepotInfoResponse" name="getDepotInfoResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDispatchPoints">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getDispatchPoints" name="getDispatchPoints"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getDispatchPointsResponse" name="getDispatchPointsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="bookOrder">
<wsdl:input message="tns:bookOrder" name="bookOrder"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:bookOrderResponse" name="bookOrderResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getCountries">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getCountries" name="getCountries"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getCountriesResponse" name="getCountriesResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrder">
<wsdl:input message="tns:confirmOrder" name="confirmOrder"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:confirmOrderResponse" name="confirmOrderResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getOrder">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getOrder" name="getOrder"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getOrderResponse" name="getOrderResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="returnTicket">
<wsdl:input message="tns:returnTicket" name="returnTicket"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:returnTicketResponse" name="returnTicketResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDocTypes">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getDocTypes" name="getDocTypes"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getDocTypesResponse" name="getDocTypesResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getTicket">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getTicket" name="getTicket"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getTicketResponse" name="getTicketResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="updateTicket">
<wsdl:input message="tns:updateTicket" name="updateTicket"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:updateTicketResponse" name="updateTicketResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrderWithFare">
<wsdl:input message="tns:confirmOrderWithFare" name="confirmOrderWithFare"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:confirmOrderWithFareResponse" name="confirmOrderWithFareResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="cancelTicket">
<wsdl:input message="tns:cancelTicket" name="cancelTicket"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:cancelTicketResponse" name="cancelTicketResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRace">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRace" name="getRace"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRaceResponse" name="getRaceResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRegions">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRegions" name="getRegions"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRegionsResponse" name="getRegionsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrderEx">
<wsdl:input message="tns:confirmOrderEx" name="confirmOrderEx"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:confirmOrderExResponse" name="confirmOrderExResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="cancelOrder">
<wsdl:input message="tns:cancelOrder" name="cancelOrder"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:cancelOrderResponse" name="cancelOrderResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="echo">
<wsdl:input message="tns:echo" name="echo"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:echoResponse" name="echoResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDepots">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getDepots" name="getDepots"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getDepotsResponse" name="getDepotsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceStops">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRaceStops" name="getRaceStops"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRaceStopsResponse" name="getRaceStopsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceSummary">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRaceSummary" name="getRaceSummary"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRaceSummaryResponse" name="getRaceSummaryResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getPointDepots">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getPointDepots" name="getPointDepots"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getPointDepotsResponse" name="getPointDepotsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceSeats">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRaceSeats" name="getRaceSeats"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRaceSeatsResponse" name="getRaceSeatsResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getTicketTypes">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getTicketTypes" name="getTicketTypes"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getTicketTypesResponse" name="getTicketTypesResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getReference">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getReference" name="getReference"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getReferenceResponse" name="getReferenceResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaces">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getRaces" name="getRaces"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getRacesResponse" name="getRacesResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SoapJsonServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SoapJsonService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getVersion">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getVersion">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getVersionResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getArrivalPoints">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getArrivalPoints">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getArrivalPointsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDispatchPoints">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getDispatchPoints">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getDispatchPointsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDepotInfo">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getDepotInfo">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getDepotInfoResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="bookOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="bookOrder">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="bookOrderResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getCountries">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getCountries">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getCountriesResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="confirmOrder">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="confirmOrderResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getOrder">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getOrderResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="returnTicket">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="returnTicket">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="returnTicketResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDocTypes">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getDocTypes">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getDocTypesResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getTicket">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getTicket">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getTicketResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="updateTicket">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="updateTicket">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="updateTicketResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrderWithFare">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="confirmOrderWithFare">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="confirmOrderWithFareResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="cancelTicket">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="cancelTicket">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="cancelTicketResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRace">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRace">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRaceResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRegions">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRegions">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRegionsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="confirmOrderEx">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="confirmOrderEx">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="confirmOrderExResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="cancelOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="cancelOrder">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="cancelOrderResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="echo">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="echo">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="echoResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getDepots">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getDepots">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getDepotsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceStops">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRaceStops">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRaceStopsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceSummary">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRaceSummary">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRaceSummaryResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getPointDepots">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getPointDepots">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getPointDepotsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaceSeats">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRaceSeats">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRaceSeatsResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getTicketTypes">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getTicketTypes">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getTicketTypesResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getReference">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getReference">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getReferenceResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="getRaces">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getRaces">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getRacesResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SoapJsonServiceImplService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:SoapJsonServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="SoapJsonServiceImplPort">
<soap:address location="http://cluster.avtovokzal.ru/gds113/soap/json"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы понять, как посылать запросы к серверу. Обычно работаю с REST-архитектурой, но возникла необходимость поработать с SOAP. Как правильно составить запрос, например, в Postman, на примере хотя бы запроса `getCountries()`?

Comment: Для начала, стоило бы уточнять язык, на котором вы пишете, ибо вопрос становиться слишком общий, да и мало просматриваемый. Далее, стоило бы указать сам сервис (если возможно), с котором мы могли бы работать. Ну и на последок, вы сами что-то пробовали? Ведь найти это очень легко, пишем просто `soap json web service c#` и находим нужное, например [это](https://tproger.ru/translations/restful-service-asp-net/)...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а без привязки с базовому URL можно описать? Просто данные не для публики. Сам пробовал посылать запросы, но с форматом не разобрался, поэтому пришел сюда

Comment: Хорошо, вот вам тогда [тестовый](https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso) сервер (заметьте, что там показывается какой тип данных должен быть отправлен и куда), вот вам [мануал](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/making-soap-requests/), как сделать это в Postman, а с вашим языком программирования думаю разберетесь сами.